# Generate all possible combinations for Columns(cross join or Cartesian product)

Tags: google-sheets, cartesian-product, cross-join

I have a Google SpreadSheets doc with three columns A, B and C.

I need to populate the Column C with all the possible combinations of the values in Columns A and B. Please take a look a the capture to see what I mean.

I found this to be done in Excel, [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/654871-how-generate-all-possible-combinations-two-lists-without-macro.html#post3246600), but it doesn't work in google spreadsheets.

The formula should be useful even for more columns (e.g.: four instead of two)

Can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update 201810**

Original formula crashes for a big dataset. I described a way to make cross-join with any size of data [here](https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com/2017/12/22/generate-all-possible-combinations-for-columns-in-google-spreadsheets/).

---

Try formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(rept(concatenate(A2:A&char(9)),counta(B2:B)),char(9)))
 &" "&transpose(split(concatenate(rept(B2:B&char(9),counta(A2:A))),char(9))))
```

The result:

```
car red
train red
car yellow
train yellow
car blue
train blue
```

You may use it again to add another list:

[image]

The formula is in cells `C2` and `E2`,

`C2` is:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(rept(concatenate(A2:A&char(9)),counta(B2:B)),char(9)))&" "&transpose(split(concatenate(rept(B2:B&char(9),counta(A2:A))),char(9))) )
```

and `E2` is:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(rept(concatenate(C2:C&char(9)),counta(D2:D)),char(9)))&" "&transpose(split(concatenate(rept(D2:D&char(9),counta(C2:C))),char(9))) )
```

Comment: Should I insert this formula in a single cell? '=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(rept(concatenate(A2:A&char(9)),counta(B2:B)),char(9)))&""&transpose(split(concatenate(rept(B2:B&char(9),counta(A2:A))),char(9))))'
This is what I did but I get an error message.
Why did you split the formula in two parts?

Comment: Sorry but I can't get it: here the spreadsheet (you can edit), can you paste your formula there: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z80MNKML4m7YKXn2SfHVZwO0mPs889MX0DXfk6iKx5k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You have to replace commas by semicolon `;` in formulas. It is regional settings. I changed file settings region to US and it worked.

Answer (score 48):

in post-pandemic new world we can solve this with:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(A2:A3&" "&TRANSPOSE(B2:B4)))
```

[image]

to account for future expansion we can do:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:A; A2:A<>"")&" "&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:B; B2:B<>""))))
```

[image]

for 3 columns:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(A2:A; A2:A<>"")&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(B2:B; B2:B<>"")))&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(C2:C; C2:C<>""))))
```

[image]

4 columns:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(A2:A; A2:A<>"")&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(B2:B; B2:B<>"")))&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(C2:C; C2:C<>"")))&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(D2:D; D2:D<>""))))
```

[image]

---

---

**for more see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74160711/5632629**

---

---

Comment: Awesome! And to print them in separate columns instead of one follow the example here: =ArrayFormula(split(flatten(transpose(filter(B2:B; B2:B <> "")) & "," & (flatten(filter(C2:C; C2:C <> "") & "," & transpose(filter(D2:D; D2:D <> ""))))); ","))
 
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/61770165/create-automatically-all-combinations-of-multiple-columns-each-one-of-different-size?hl=en

Answer (score 6):

Now that we have `LAMBDA` and the Lambda Helper Functions, we can solve this problem nicely using [`REDUCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597)

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(range,A2:C,
       SPLIT(
         REDUCE(,
           SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(range)),
           LAMBDA(acc,i,
             TOCOL(acc&"ζ"&TOROW(INDEX(range,,i),3)))),
         "ζ")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

***Here's one more approach to add to the collection***:

```
=let(range,A:D,data,filter(range,bycol(range,lambda(Σ,counta(Σ)))<>0),
     count,bycol(data,lambda(Σ,counta(Σ))), column,sequence(1,columns(data),1),
     first,tocol(map(tocol(choosecols(data,1),1),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,product(ifna(filter(count,column>1),1)),Σ)))),
     if(max(column)=1,first,reduce(first,sequence(1,max(column)-1,2,1),lambda(a,c,{a,
           tocol(map(tocol(map(tocol(choosecols(data,c),1),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,product(ifna(filter(count,column>c),1)),Σ)))),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,product(filter(count,column<c)),Σ))),,1)}))))
```

[image]

***No change in formula needed even when the data is in just 3 columns (`and non-adjacent too`)***
[image]

***`2 columns` with still the same formula***
[image]

***An extension to this formula can be used to create unique pair combinations ([as described in this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47922267/5479575)) while excluding\limiting the duplicates (`1,1 | 2,2 | 3,3.... and 1,2 | 2,1 | 1,3 | 3,1....`)***

```
=let(range,index(query({A:A,A:A},"Where Col1 is not null")),data,filter(range,bycol(range,lambda(Σ,counta(Σ)))<>0),
     count,bycol(data,lambda(Σ,counta(Σ))), column,sequence(1,columns(data),1),
     first,tocol(map(tocol(choosecols(data,1),1),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,product(ifna(filter(count,column>1),1)),Σ)))),
     combo_,if(max(column)=1,first,reduce(first,sequence(1,max(column)-1,2,1),lambda(a,c,{a,
           tocol(map(tocol(map(tocol(choosecols(data,c),1),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,product(ifna(filter(count,column>c),1)),Σ)))),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,product(filter(count,column<c)),Σ))),,1)}))),
     Λ,byrow(combo_,lambda(Σ,if(index(Σ,,1)>=index(Σ,,2),,Σ))),
       filter(Λ,index(Λ,,1)<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: Impressive. With larger datasets, your `reduce()` appears to have slightly better performance than the iterative formula in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution.

A named function `CARTESIAN_PRODUCT`:

```
=IF(COLUMNS(range) = 1, IFNA(FILTER(range, range <> "")), LAMBDA(sub_product, last_col, REDUCE(, SEQUENCE(ROWS(sub_product)), LAMBDA(acc, cur, LAMBDA(new_range, IF(cur = 1, new_range, {acc; new_range}))({ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(last_col)), INDEX(sub_product, cur,))), last_col}))))(CARTESIAN_PRODUCT(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(range, ROWS(range), COLUMNS(range) - 1)), LAMBDA(r, IFNA(FILTER(r, r <> "")))(INDEX(range,, COLUMNS(range)))))
```

(in a little bit [more readable](https://pastebin.com/raw/2dFry2Yr) formatting)

The only argument is `range` which specifies the columns with the values. Empty cells will be ignored.

It uses recursion and does not use query smashing or string splitting. It works with any number of columns.

[image]

Comment: When trying to use that, I get a syntax error. For some reason in my case the first `range` param in `FILTER` isn't recognized as the named argument (and coloured orange), even though the second one is. Weird. If it's not a problem, could you check if the line that you pasted here still works in the current GSHeets for you?

Comment: @JoannaFalkowska checked, it works without any change. Maybe you have language settings other than US, so parameter delimiter in functions is `;` instead of `,`?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here's another one from me. No recursion this time, quite fast. Should be made a named function with a single parameter `range`:

```
=LET(
    ref,
    BYCOL(range, LAMBDA(c, IFNA(FILTER(c, c <> "")))),
    nums,
    BYCOL(ref, LAMBDA(c, MAX(1, COUNTA(c)))),
    total,
    PRODUCT(nums),
    divs,
    SCAN(total, nums, LAMBDA(acc, cur, acc / cur)),
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        VLOOKUP(
            MOD(INT(SEQUENCE(total, 1,) / divs), nums),
            {
                SEQUENCE(ROWS(ref), 1,),
                ref
            },
            SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(ref), 2),)
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing that kishkin, it's simple and elegant. For some reason, the performance is not as good as I expected. With a larger dataset (36k result rows), it is about `2x` faster than a minified recursive formula, but rockinfreakshow's `reduce()` clocks in at about `6x`. A binary search `vlookup()` should be fast so this is a surprise. See [the benchmark](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hzuAqileCdrB1pVKAiAbWmstBL63FoXot4QBpmwWAjA/edit#gid=1908738223).

Comment: too many vlookups, i guess :) thanks for the benchmarks

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @nicolasZ's comment for those (like myself) not so familiar with sheets syntax:

If you want to create the combinations but split into unique columns you can follow a very similar patter to @player0's answer but wrapping everything in `ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT( ...)," "`.

What this does is split the result in a single column by a space (`" "`) and then distribute this into the next `N` columns.

Explicitly, to combine 5 columns of data I used:

```
= ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT( FLATTEN(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>"")&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(C2:C, C2:C<>"")))&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(D2:D, D2:D<>"")))&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(E2:E, E2:E<>"")))&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(F2:F, F2:F<>"")))," "))
```

To add more rows you simply have to add another `Flatten(` to the beginning of the command and then insert `&" "&TRANSPOSE( FILTER(F2:F, F2:F<>"")))` at the end (but before the `" "))`.

Note that there must be enough empty column/rows to expand the formula or the command will fail to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

The question specifies [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) and n-ary [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). These concepts are different from string concatenation ("car" + "red" → "car red").

Most of the existing answers use text string manipulation and `split()` which is undesirable because they may cause side effects such as converting the text string `1 2 3` to the date `2 January 2003`. Some answers use recursion through a [named function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534) that calls itself. That works, but it is often undesirable as well, because named functions need to be recreated or imported in each spreadsheet where they are to be used.

One way to implement n-ary Cartesian product in a plain vanilla Google Sheet formula without those undesirable traits is to use a [recursive lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75789114/13045193). The formula below takes a range of any number of columns and gives all ordered n-tuples of their non-blank values, column-wise:

```
=let( 
  table, A2:D, 
  blank, iferror(1/0), 
  first_, lambda(array, tocol(choosecols(array, 1), true)), 
  rest_, lambda(n, choosecols(table, sequence(1, columns(table) - n, n + 1))), 
  wrap_, lambda(array, wrapCount, wraprows(tocol(array, true), wrapCount)), 

  cartesian_, lambda(a, b, wrap_( 
    byrow(a, lambda(row, 
      reduce(blank, sequence(rows(b)), lambda(acc, i, 
        { acc, row, chooserows(b, i) } 
      ) ) 
    ) ), 
    columns(a) + columns(b) 
  ) ), 

  iterate_, lambda( 
    self, a, b, if(iserror(b), a, 
      self(self, cartesian_(a, first_(b)), rest_(columns(a) + 1)) 
    ) 
  ), 

  iterate_(iterate_, first_(table), rest_(1)) 
)
```

The same can also be done in an iterative fashion. The formula below will perform about two times faster than `split()` based solutions with larger datasets:

```
=let( 
  table, A2:D, 
  numCols, columns(table), 
  colIndices, sequence(1, numCols), 
  column_, lambda(colIndex, tocol(choosecols(table, colIndex), 1)), 
  numColRows, bycol(colIndices, lambda(i, rows(column_(i)))), 
  numColRows_, lambda(i, index(numColRows, 0, i)), 
  colIndicesToRight_, lambda(i, sequence(1, numCols - i, i + 1)), 
  numColRowsToRight_, lambda(i, bycol(colIndicesToRight_(i), numColRows_)), 
  numCombos_, lambda(i, iferror(product(numColRowsToRight_(i)), 1)), 
  repeatCells_, lambda(colIndex, tocol( 
    map(column_(colIndex), lambda(cell, 
      bycol(sequence(1, numCombos_(colIndex)), lambda(_, cell)) 
    ) )  
  ) ), 
  repeatGroup_, lambda(g, n, tocol(bycol(sequence(1, n), lambda(_, g)), 0, 1)), 
  fillColumn_, lambda(colIndex, let( 
    group, repeatCells_(colIndex), 
    repeatGroup_(group, product(numColRows) / rows(group))
  ) ), 
  if( 
    min(numColRows) = 0, "All columns must have at least one item.", 
    if( 
      numCols * product(numColRows) > 10^6, "Too many results.", 
      bycol(colIndices, fillColumn_) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The identifiers in the above formulas use a naming convention where a lambda `function_` name definition has a trailing underscore.

Both formulas will work with any number of columns and give results like these:

| source data |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | X |
| b | 2 | Y |
| c |  |  |

| × Cartesian |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | X |
| a | 1 | Y |
| a | 2 | X |
| a | 2 | Y |
| b | 1 | X |
| b | 1 | Y |
| b | 2 | X |
| b | 2 | Y |
| c | 1 | X |
| c | 1 | Y |
| c | 2 | X |
| c | 2 | Y |