# Google sheet, 4 columns, all possible combination

Tags: google-sheets

I have four columns and need to populate the fifth column with all possibles variation of combined words from all 4 columns. See the attached image for an example of the source columns.

Thank you for your help
[image]

Comment: what do you mean with this `all possibles variation of combine words with all 4 columns`?

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: @KhrisnaGunanasurya His question is how to generate such all possible combinations from all columns. It's a valid question. I don't understand all the downvotes.

Comment: and with based of what for the combinations? or is it just put the altogether? Well I'm not one of them (the downvotes) @ttarchala

Comment: So basically I need all possible combination with all  the words from the 4 columns.  For example
1 - Top Visual Logo Design Services
2 - Top Graphic Logo Design Services
3 - Top Professional Logo Design Services
4 - Top Visual Logo Design Work
5 - Top Graphic Logo Design Work
6 - Top Professional Logo Design Work
I need all cells to be used. SO that all possible keyword combination to be met.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the solution for generating all possible combinations from 2 columns:
[Generate all possible combinations for Columns in Google SpreadSheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805885/generate-all-possible-combinations-for-columns-in-google-spreadsheets)

Once you understand the solution, you will be able to re-apply it to 4 columns (for example, by doing the first 2, then the second 2, then doubling back on the results).