# In Google sheets is there a simple method to create a list based off row and column cells

Tags: google-sheets

If I have a google sheet with the following rows and columns

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Red | Green | Yellow |
| Apple |  |  |  |
| Grape |  |  |  |
| Pear |  |  |  |

Is there a formula to create the following list.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Red |  |  |
| Apple | Green |  |  |
| Apple | Yellow |  |  |
| Grape | Red |  |  |
| Grape | Green |  |  |
| Grape | Yellow |  |  |
| Pear | Red |  |  |
| Pear | Green |  |  |
| Pear | Yellow |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this formula:

`=INDEX(FLATTEN(A2:A4&" "&B1:D1))`

[image: ex]

References:
[Generate all possible combinations for Columns(cross join or Cartesian product)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805885/generate-all-possible-combinations-for-columnscross-join-or-cartesian-product)
[Create a combined list from two separate lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364641/create-a-combined-list-from-two-separate-lists)