# Cartesian / Cross Join in Google Sheets for comma separated values

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I'm in the process of building an inventory of products for a webstore. The parent products contain a comma separated list of attributes that are available. If it were a tshirt, it would show `xs,s,m,l,xl` with colours in a list in an other field `b,r,g,y` (blue, red, green, yellow).

To generate the child inventory, we need to create a cartesian join in Google Sheets of 6 fields, 5 of them have comma separated lists which need to be split and then joined together again within the cartesian join. Some rows don't have values in certain fields so the formula would have to account for that.

I have tried this method and variations of it without success. I can get it to work for 1 row but it falls down as soon as I use a whole column.

[Generate all possible combinations for Columns in Google SpreadSheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805885/generate-all-possible-combinations-for-columns-in-google-spreadsheets)

I have included an example sheet with test values. I have also included an example of an expected result for each row.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pi1zjJuiWRJ2iPZo2Ve4dAekyVnGq5Tc0z3rgev_Ikw/edit?usp=sharing

I'd like to try doing this without the use of Google Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A2&TRANSPOSE(REGEXREPLACE(
SPLIT(FLATTEN(
SPLIT(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B2,","))&IF(C2="",,"-"&SPLIT(C2,","))&"♦︎"),"♦︎")
&"-"&SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,D2:F2),",")&"♦︎"),"♦︎")
,"-$",)))
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know how I'd then get that to work across the column of values instead of just one row? I may have been a bit ambiguous about that.

Comment: You can do it by simply removing the first `TRANSPOSE`.  But your data are in rows that outputting across the column would make you unable to apply the formula the other rows.

Answer (score 0):

see:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SPLIT(QUERY(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(ROW(A2:A)&"×"&A2:A, A2:A<>IF(,,))&
 SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)+ROW(A2)-1)=IF(,,),,IF(B2:B=IF(,,), "×"&ROW(B2:B)&"×♦", "×"&ROW(B2:B)&"×-"&SPLIT(B2:B, ",")))), ","))&
 SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)+ROW(A2)-1)=IF(,,),,IF(C2:C=IF(,,), "×"&ROW(C2:C)&"×♦", "×"&ROW(C2:C)&"×-"&SPLIT(C2:C, ",")))), ","))&
 SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)+ROW(A2)-1)=IF(,,),,IF(D2:D=IF(,,), "×"&ROW(D2:D)&"×♦", "×"&ROW(D2:D)&"×-"&SPLIT(D2:D, ",")))), ","))&
 SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)+ROW(A2)-1)=IF(,,),,IF(E2:E=IF(,,), "×"&ROW(E2:E)&"×♦", "×"&ROW(E2:E)&"×-"&SPLIT(E2:E, ",")))), ","))&
 SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)+ROW(A2)-1)=IF(,,),,IF(F2:F=IF(,,), "×"&ROW(F2:F)&"×♦", "×"&ROW(F2:F)&"×-"&SPLIT(F2:F, ",")))), ","))), 
 "where Col1 contains '♦'"), "×"), 
 "select Col2,Col4,Col6,Col8,Col10,Col12  
  where Col1=Col3 and Col3=Col5 and Col5=Col7 and Col7=Col9 and Col9=Col11"), "♦", IF(,,))),,999^99))), " ", IF(,,)), 
 "where not Col1 contains '--'"))
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18DignIgGEsA76uWdVnHDNdV8C4ecLJEopy3mRQ8rC-I/edit#gid=0)

Comment: What a legend. That works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: We've tested the solution further and found that this doesn't work for anything past 8 or 9 rows. We get an `array too large` error. If we remove the `unique` we find that the formula generates 3000+ results from 2 rows. The final formula would need to be able to handle 6000 rows of data, not just 8 or 9.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))=IF(,,),,
 A2:A&SPLIT(B2:B, ","))), "where Col1 is not null")&
 IFERROR(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))=IF(,,),,
 IF(C2:C=IF(,,), IF(E2:E=IF(,,), CHAR(32),
 SUBSTITUTE("-"&E2:E, ",", ",-")), SUBSTITUTE("-"&C2:C, ",", ",-"))))&"",
 "where Col1 is not null limit "&COLUMNS(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, B2:B), ","))), ",")))&
 IF(IF(,,)=IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(IF(,,)=IFERROR(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))=IF(,,),,
 IF(C2:C=IF(,,), IF(E2:E=IF(,,), CHAR(32), E2:E), C2:C)))&"",
 "where Col1 is not null limit "&COLUMNS(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, B2:B), ","))), ",")),, 
 QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))=IF(,,),,
 IF(D2:D=IF(,,), IF(F2:F=IF(,,), CHAR(32), F2:F), D2:D)))&"",
 "where Col1 is not null limit "&COLUMNS(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, B2:B), ","))))), ",")), 0/0, 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IF(,,)=IFERROR(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))=IF(,,),,
 IF(C2:C=IF(,,), IF(E2:E=IF(,,), CHAR(32), E2:E), C2:C)))&"",
 "where Col1 is not null limit "&COLUMNS(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, B2:B), ","))), ",")),, 
 QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))=IF(,,),,
 IF(D2:D=IF(,,), IF(F2:F=IF(,,), CHAR(32),
 SUBSTITUTE("-"&F2:F, ",", ",-")), SUBSTITUTE("-"&D2:D, ",", ",-"))))&"",
 "where Col1 is not null limit "&COLUMNS(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, B2:B), ","))))), ","))),
 "where Col1 contains '-'"), CHAR(32), ))
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18DignIgGEsA76uWdVnHDNdV8C4ecLJEopy3mRQ8rC-I/edit#gid=1841888222)