# Join Tables NxN in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 tables (matrixes) for instance

```
a
b
c
```

and

```
x
y
z
```

I would like to the final result to be

```
a x
a y
a z
b x
b y
b z
c x
c y
c z
```

How can it be possible

Comment: a, b, c and x, y, z are text or numeric?

Comment: It is unclear whether final results should be joined in one cell for each row, or split across two columns per row with one in each column. In the interest of efficiency, it would also help if you gave the actual ranges where the original `a b c` and `x y z` reside in your sheet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68775825/5632629

Answer (score 1):

Desired output is unclear whether it is in a single or separate columns, so I'll provide both outcomes:

#### Single column (C1):

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(FILTER(A:A, A:A<>"")&" "&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B, B:B<>""))))
```

#### Separate columns (D1):

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(A:A, A:A<>"")&" "&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B, B:B<>""))), " "))
```

#### Output:

[image: output]