# Generate possible combinations into separate columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I found many solutions online, but they are generating combinations as combined text. I want to generate them into separate columns like on picture below.

**Formula should be in C1, based on columns A and B.**
New rows in A and B will populate new rows (combinations) in C and D.

[Manual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UegBJ.png)

Comment: See the second example in the documentation for the FLATTEN function described as a Cartesian Product: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en

Comment: If you need to combine more than two columns, see [Generate all possible combinations for Columns(cross join or Cartesian product)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76126924/13045193).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in C1

```
=arrayformula(SPLIT(flatten(offset(A1,,,COUNTA(A:A))&"|"&transpose(offset(B1,,,COUNTA(B:B)))),"|"))
```

[image]