# Modify an existing named function that returns a Cartesian product / cross join by adding an argument that specifies the # of columns/values per row

Tags: google-sheets, cartesian-product, cross-join, named-function

I found the following Google Sheets named function `CARTESIAN_PRODUCT` as an answer to a related question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74914486/21162264):

`=IF(COLUMNS(range) = 1, IFNA(FILTER(range, range <> "")), LAMBDA(sub_product, last_col, REDUCE(, SEQUENCE(ROWS(sub_product)), LAMBDA(acc, cur, LAMBDA(new_range, IF(cur = 1, new_range, {acc; new_range}))({ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(last_col)), INDEX(sub_product, cur,))), last_col}))))(CARTESIAN_PRODUCT(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(range, ROWS(range), COLUMNS(range) - 1)), LAMBDA(r, IFNA(FILTER(r, r <> "")))(INDEX(range,, COLUMNS(range)))))`

This function has 1 argument, `range`, which specifies the columns with the values, and returns a Cartesian product / cross join with the same number of columns as are included in the range:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l2yV.png)

I would like modify this named function by adding an argument that specifies the # of columns/values per row.  For example, I'd like to be able to take the same range as in the image above and return 2 columns instead of 3:

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX1bU.png)

I found a similar pair of named functions that work together to return all unique combinations from a single column (which I know is not a Cartesian product / cross join) and that include an additional argument, `r`, that specifies the # of columns/values per row [Here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/188986371?hl=en&msgid=189413158):

`COMBINATIONS_INDICES`:

`=LAMBDA(f_range; LAMBDA(f_range_rows; IF(OR(r <= 0; r > f_range_rows);; IF(r = f_range_rows; SEQUENCE(1; r); LAMBDA(n; max_inds; REDUCE(SEQUENCE(1; r); SEQUENCE(PRODUCT(SEQUENCE(n)) / PRODUCT(SEQUENCE(n - r)) / PRODUCT(SEQUENCE(r)) - 1); LAMBDA(acc; cur; {acc; LAMBDA(ind; IF(ind = 1; SEQUENCE(1; r; INDEX(acc; ROWS(acc); 1) + 1); {ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(INDEX(acc; ROWS(acc);); 1; ind - 1)\ SEQUENCE(1; r - ind + 1; INDEX(acc; ROWS(acc); ind) + 1)}))(MATCH(2; ARRAYFORMULA(1 / (max_inds - INDEX(acc; ROWS(acc);) > 0))))})))(f_range_rows; SEQUENCE(1; r; f_range_rows - r + 1)))))(ROWS(f_range)))(FLATTEN(range))`

and `COMBINATIONS`:

`=LAMBDA(comb_inds; IF(comb_inds = "";; LAMBDA(f_range; MAP(comb_inds; LAMBDA(i; INDEX(f_range; i))))(FLATTEN(range))))(COMBINATIONS_INDICES(range; r))`

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImONP.png)

So far I've been unsuccessful in my attempts to add an argument like what can be found in the `COMBINATIONS_INDICES` and `COMBINATIONS` functions that specifies the # of columns/values per row to the `CARTESIAN_PRODUCT` function.

Can this be done?

Edit:

[Here is a screenshot of how the result would look like if we had 4 columns and wanted to restrict it to 2 and 3 columns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuSFi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this named function:

`=IFERROR(FILTER(SPLIT(REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(range)),LAMBDA(a,c,FLATTEN(a&"ζ"&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(INDEX(range,,c),INDEX(range,,c)<>""))))),"ζ"),TRANSPOSE(QUERY({SEQUENCE(cols);SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(range)-cols,1,0,0)},"where Col1 is not null"))),NA())`

The arguments are `range` and `cols`.

Comment: Unfortunately this named function does not return a Cartesian product, as it appears to remove all the values from any columns that aren't returned as specified by the `cols` argument.  I'm still looking for a Cartesian product, just one that fits within a specified number of columns.

Comment: how would the result look like if we had 4 columns and wanted to restrict it to 2 and 3 columns?

Comment: just added a screenshot to the end of my post.  I think I captured all possible combinations for 2 and 3 columns.  Thanks for your help!