# Multiply all possible combinations for rows - Cross Join set row with multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, cartesian-product, cross-join

Hi I have a similar problem in Google sheets that is solved in this thread:

[Generate all possible combinations for Columns(cross join or Cartesian product)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805885/generate-all-possible-combinations-for-columnscross-join-or-cartesian-product?noredirect=1&lq=1)

i am trying to join multiple rows with number of columns
i tried with FLATTEN & TRANSPOSE but wasn't given me what i wanted

Below is a google sheet showing what i have (DATA) and wanted (SHOULD LOOK LIKE)
[DATASET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fZgmqcdR8jz5G2iQBGzbF5QlytKYAt3dTUFSfcJRJ2A/edit#gid=629408463)

any help would be appreciated!

i tried with excel & power query which is fine but i want to do it in google sheet but can't

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). The sample spreadsheet shows that you want to re-order the "wide" data table into a row-oriented "tall" table. That is known as an "[unpivot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unpivot)". The question specifies [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) but that is a different concept that involves generating combinations of various fields. Please [edit] the question to describe what you want more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

The Cartesian product that automatically expands as new rows are added can be performed like this:

```cpp
SPLIT(
  TOCOL(
    DATA!A2:A&"|"&DATA!B2:B&"|"&
    DATA!C2:C&"|"&DATA!D2:D&"|"&
    DATA!E1:P1&"|"&DATA!E2:P,3),
  "|")
```

However, all those ranges have empty rows at the bottom which slow down the formula so it's better to remove them:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(data,QUERY(DATA!A2:P,"where Col1 is not null"),
       months,DATA!E1:P1,
       QUERY(
         SPLIT(
           TOCOL(
             INDEX(data,,1)&"|"&INDEX(data,,2)&"|"&
             INDEX(data,,3)&"|"&INDEX(data,,4)&"|"&
             months&"|"&CHOOSECOLS(data,SEQUENCE(12,1,5)),3),"|"),
         "where Col6 is not null")))
```

Answer (score 1):

The question specifies [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) but the desired results provided in the sample spreadsheet indicate that what the asker wants is an [unpivot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unpivot).

Here's how to unpivot the data using a lambda function:

```
=let( 
  unpivot_, lambda(data, numFixedCols, numColsPerGroup, let(k,n(numFixedCols),d,if(k,data,hstack(sequence(rows(data)),data)),f,if(k,k,1),g,numColsPerGroup,r_,lambda(t,o,h,chooserows(t,sequence(h,1,o))),c_,lambda(t,o,w,choosecols(t,sequence(1,w,o))),s_,lambda(r,c,h,w,r_(c_(d,c,w),r,h)),h,hstack(s_(1,1,1,f),"Month","Amount"),i,sequence(1,(columns(d)-f)/g,f+1,g),a,reduce(h,sequence(rows(d)-1,1,2),lambda(a,r,let(x,s_(r,1,1,f),b,reduce(tocol(æ,2),i,lambda(y,c,let(z,s_(r,c,1,g),if(single(z)="",y,vstack(y,hstack(x,s_(1,c,1,1),z)))))),vstack(a,b)))),if(k,a,choosecols(a,sequence(1,columns(a)-1,2))))), 

  unpivot_(DATA!A1:P, 4, 1) 
)
```

The formula is in cell `doubleunary!A1` in the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fZgmqcdR8jz5G2iQBGzbF5QlytKYAt3dTUFSfcJRJ2A/edit#gid=445635689).

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535)
and
[lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula (see your gs ***harun24hr*** sheet).

```
=QUERY(
HSTACK(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(DATA!A2:D5)*COLUMNS(DATA!E1:P5),ROWS(DATA!A2:D5),LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(DATA!A2:D5, ROUNDUP(r/COLUMNS(DATA!E1:P5),0),c))),
FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(TEXTJOIN("|",1,DATA!E1:P1)&"|",4),"|")),
FLATTEN(DATA!E2:P5)),
"select * where Col6 is not null",0)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that gets the correct amounts.

Comment: @doubleunary Thanks for catching it. Amount was correct but months were wrongly putted. I have corrected the formula.